# Как js скрипт влияет на css атрибут цвета текста?

Tags: javascript, css

В тэге р есть text. В css3 задан цвет текста:    color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.3); -   оранжевый. В js создается эффект падающих сверху букв текста:

```
var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

function textEffect(animationName) {

    var text = paragraph.innerHTML,
        сhars = text.length,
        newText = '',
        animation = animationName,
        char,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < chars; i += 1) {
        newText += '<i>' + text.charAt(i) + '</i>';
    }

    paragraph.innerHTML = newText;

    var wrappedChars = document.getElementsByTagName('i'),
        wrappedCharsLen = wrappedChars.length,
        j = 0;

    function addEffect() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            wrappedChars[j].className = animation;
            j += 1;
            if (j < wrappedCharsLen) {
                addEffect();
            }
        }, 100)
    }

    addEffect();
}
```

В результате выпадает текст белого цвета (буквы=char - белые).

Подскажите, почему и как исправить?

Мучаюсь 3-ий день на лок. хосте (Denwer).

Comment: залили бы на jsfiddle или что-то подобное, тогда можно разобраться

Comment: вполне себе закрашивает в нужный цвет https://jsfiddle.net/xv4hpvsx/2/

Comment: как следствие - ошибка где-то еще.... либо нужен ПОООЛНЫЙ код того что есть.. и html и css и js и всё всё всё

Comment: предположу вообще, что где-то (может в CSS) задан цвет для тега `<i>`. Вот он-то и портит всё